# Mac OSX HTTP slowness

Tags: networking, http, osx-mavericks

I've been having internet issues at work for a while now. I'm using Mavericks on a 2013 retina MBP, and the internet will repeatedly just start being abysmally slow connecting to websites.

Websites will often just hang at the "waiting for www.website.com" on the status bar in Chrome, (or equivalents in Firefox or Safari)
I've tried using Wi-Fi and/or ethernet (through thunderbolt) and the issue persists. As far as I know, my work doesn't use a proxy server, and other computers seem to be unaffected.

Weird things are that:

1. Usually, when I'm connected on both wifi and ethernet, if I pull the cable on the ethernet, pages that were sitting there at the loading screen will suddenly finally load, as if they were suddenly "unclogged" But, this issue doesn't go away if I use only ethernet or only wi-fi (even if I disable them)

2. Pings are almost always responsive- right now I'm trying to reach google.com and it won't load, but pings are responding in the <50ms range.

3. traceroute also doesn't show any obvious problems.

4. Rebooting usually temporarily fixes the problem.

5. When this problem occurs, it seems to only affect HTTP - FTP seems to work, SMB shares seem to work.

I'm still learning OS X, so I'm not even sure where to start in diagnosing this problem. Any ideas, utilities, command line scripts to find the problem? I tried looking at wireshark logs, but it was a firehose of completely incomprehensible information to me. Is there some tool or utiity that will tell me what is going on with this?